# Require a UITextField to take 5 digits

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITextField set up to show a number pad.  How do I require the user to enter exactly 5 digits?

I poked around and saw I should use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` but I'm not quite understanding how to implement that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use this when the user leaves the textfield/validates with a button

```
if ([myTextField.text length] != 5){

//Show alert or some other warning, like a red text

}else{
 //Authorized text, proceed with whatever you are doing
}
```

Now if you want to count the chars WHILE the user is typing, you might use in `viewDidLoad`

```
[myTextfield addTarget: self action@selector(textfieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventsEditingChanged]

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)theTextField{
 //This happens every time the textfield changes
}
```

Please make sure to ask questions in the comments if you need more help :)

Comment: You're right, i edited differently so it's still as clear as possible. Thumbs up to you

Comment: Thanks @PaulR and Zil this is what I wanted.

Comment: I don't understand why U all writing lenght instead of length @PaulR

Comment: It's a typo, and then probably just copy-pasted around in these comments. I'm fixing it :)

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself a delegate of `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
        NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
        NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

        NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

        BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

        //desired length less than or equal to 5
        return newLength <= 5 || returnKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {

    NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];

    return [self validateText: newText]; // Return YES if newText is acceptable 

}
```